# Согласование рода

Tags: род

> **Эта** игра что надо

или

> **Это** игра что надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, **это**.

**Эта** is when you contrast it with an implied **та игра** (or **те игры**) that aren't quite up to par.

Answer (score 6):

Both are acceptable.

*Эта игра что надо* = *This game is good*

*Это игра что надо* = *It is a good game*

Comment: You're correct but first variant is more natural.